# Easiest wasy to find full calendar years, months, days and hours between two time stamps in .net

Tags: .net, algorithm, datetime

What I would like to do is as follows

Given two dates e.g. March 02, 1998 and September 25, 2011. How to get split the interval into

1. March 02, 1998 to March 31, 1998         ( 30 Days)
2. April 01, 1998 to December 31, 1998         ( 9 Months)
3. January 01, 1999 to December 31, 2010         ( 11 Years)
4. January 01, 2011 to August31, 2011         ( 8 Months)
5. September 01, 2011 to September 25, 2011         ( 30 Days)

   However if any of the interval doesn't exist, we don't wan to force include it i.e. the result will not always be days/months/years/months/days e.g.

   Given start date = '1998-02-01' and end date = '2011-03-31',
   The expect results is (Months/Years/Months)

   1998-02-01      ==>  1998-12-31
   1999-01-01      ==>  2010-12-31
   2011-01-01      ==>  2011-03-31

   Given start date = '1998-02-01' and end date = '1998-03-31',
   The expect results is (2 Months)

   1998-02-01      ==>  2011-03-31

   Given start date = '1998-01-05' and end date = '1998-02-03',
   The expect results is (Days/Days)
   1998-01-05      ==>  2011-01-31
   1998-02-01      ==>  2011-02-03

Have a look at the following in case my description does not make sense. I am trying to accomplish the same but in .net

[Algorithm to find optimal day/month/year intervals to in an arbitrary timeframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164722/algorithm-to-find-optimal-day-month-year-intervals-to-in-an-arbitrary-timeframe)

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here? To restate and clarify, you are looking to break arbitrary start and end dates into several ranges of a given span, but all 3 values (start date, end date, and time span) will be known? The next question is what have you tried?

Comment: The input to the algorithm are two time stamps;
i) startTime 
ii) endTime

And the output is range(s) of full calender days/months/years.

Comment: Ok, I think I am seeing it now that I had my coffee, you are looking to go from the start date to the end of that month in days, then that split to the end of the year in months, then to the start of the end year in years, then back down to the end date with the reverse of that process?

Comment: In response to your up date, what about a case were you skip years (eg 2010-07-01 to 2011-04-30), do you want 1 interval of 10 months, or 1 of 6 months and a second of 4 months?

Comment: @psubsee: Yup, you are right. As for you second question where have gotten so far. As for you question I don't the if else's in my solution when trying to find the months. i.e. check if end date isn't the max possible date else add a month and subtract a day from it just as Guffa did it. and then compare to the given end date. I was looking for an elegant solution coz apparently the problem isn't  that complex :(

Comment: @psubsee: You hit the bulls eye this time :) I again missed that in the problem statement. It should be only one interval of 10 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do like this:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1998, 3, 2);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2011, 9, 25);

DateTime firstMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(1);
DateTime firstYear = new DateTime(startDate.Year + 1, 1, 1);
DateTime lastYear = new DateTime(endDate.Year, 1, 1);
DateTime lastMonth = new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);

Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", startDate, firstMonth.AddDays(-1));
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", firstMonth, firstYear.AddDays(-1));
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", firstYear, lastYear.AddDays(-1));
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", lastYear, lastMonth.AddDays(-1));
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd} - {1:yyyy-MM-dd}", lastMonth, endDate);
```

Output:

```
1998-03-02 - 1998-03-31
1998-04-01 - 1998-12-31
1999-01-01 - 2010-12-31
2011-01-01 - 2011-08-31
2011-09-01 - 2011-09-25
```

Comment: I think I need to change the problem statement. The result will not always be days/months/years/months/days

Comment: @WPFAbsoluteNewBie: Then you just have to compare the start and end of the intervals with each other, and with the start and end date. If you get an interval where the start is after the end, or the start is before the start date, or the end is after the end date, it should not be included in the result. If you are left with an empty collection, just make an interval of the start date and end date.

Comment: <Sorry the formatting sucks/>

Given start date = '1998-02-01' and end date = '1998-09-25' the proposed solution will give me (assuming non leap year)

1998-02-01 - 1998-02-28 ##
1998-03-01 - 1998-08-31 ##
1998-09-01 - 1998-09-25 ##

Where as it should be 
1998-02-01 - 1998-08-31 ##
1998-09-01 - 1998-09-25 ##

Comment: @WPFAbsoluteNewBie: If you want special cases for when the start date and end date are starting and ending of months/years, then you will have to check for that specifically.